# How do I change the mysql server date using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, mysql-5.1

I need to change the server date via sql.
Preferably through my application (CL is also good).
How do I change the mysql server date using SQL?

Why:
We test a scenario that spans several weeks. To test it we need to advance the server date by that time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to change the server date or the server timezone?

If it is the server date, you have to do it at the OS level.

If it is the time zone, you can change it globally for entire database instance or for your session/connection only.

Comment: server date is what I need to change

Comment: I don't believe you can do it without falling down to the OS level.

Answer (score 0):

The SET TIMESTAMP statement affects the value returned by NOW() but not by SYSDATE()